# Powershell, find files containing keyword then rename those files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a scrip that looks for all files within a directory containing the word "Datamonitor" and rename the files using the existing name with the prefix "Datamonitor".

I tried using the SelectString cmdlet but this doesn't seem to be available for me. I found some code that could possibly be amended but I've been unable work out how.

```
$directoryToTarget=$args[0]
$wordToFind=$args[1]
$wordToReplace=$args[2]

Clear-Content log.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter *.properties -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 

$file = Get-Content $_.FullName
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $wordToFind}
If($containsWord -contains $true)
{
    Add-Content log.txt $_.FullName
    ($file) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $wordToFind , $wordToReplace } | 
     Set-Content $_.FullName
}
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me amend this to search for my keyword and include `Rename-Item -Newmane {"Datamonitor_""+$_.Name}`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will look for all *.properties files and if they contain the keyword 'DataMonitor' the file will be renamed.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter *.properties -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 

    $i = Get-Content $_ |Select-String "Datamonitor" -SimpleMatch

    if ($i -ne $null)
    {
        Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Datamonitor_'+$_.name)
    }
}
```

One drawback, however, is that this can only run once. Running it multiple times will add additional 'Datamonitor_' to the file name. This can be easily fixed though.

PS. In your question you ask for all files, then in the get-childitem, you specify a filter. I used the filter for the needs of this example, if your want all files, just remove -filter *.properties

Comment: Sorry, one more question... suppose I wanted to create a text file containing the file names of all the files containing "datamonitor" how would I do that? Could I swap out `Rename-Item` with something like `ForEach-Object{$_.Name} > C/path/file.txt`

Comment: I would use ForEach-Object{$_.Name | out-file C:\path\file.txt -append}

Answer (score 0):

```
$file | %{$_ -match $wordToFind}
```

checks for matches of `$wordToFind` in the file *name*, not the file *content*. For the latter you need something like

```
$file | ? { (Get-Content $_) -pattern $wordToFind }
```

or (better)

```
$file | ? { Select-String -LiteralPath $_ -Pattern $wordToFind }
```

Note that both ways do regular expression matches, so if `$wordToFind` contains special characters you need to properly escape them:

```
[regex]::Escape($wordToFind)
```